# Support for JSON?

Tags: xml, json, parsing, scala

Since Scala has built-in support for XML, I wonder, doesn't it have the same for JSON? If it doesn't, would it be sensible to create XML first using its built-in syntax and then convert it to JSON somehow (trying NOT to use any third-party libraries)?

Comment: why not to write json with raw string and then, for example, call `toJson` on it from some json library (spray-json?) ?

Comment: @AlexIv why not to write xml  with raw string and then, for example, call toXml on it from some xml library?

Comment: scala is still relatively new language(therefore lack of many useful libraries/features). Its big advantage is ability to work with jvm-based libraries. There is nothing easier than deploy some java json library...

Comment: You're probably better off asking _why_ questions like this over at [one of the Scala mailing lists](http://www.scala-lang.org/community/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having XML literals and related XML processing functionality in the standard library was arguably a mistake, and the `scala.xml` package is in fact [being removed from the standard library jar](http://docs.scala-lang.org/scala/2.11/) in 2.11.

One of the nice things about Scala is that it allows library writers to construct very elegant embedded DSLs, which means there's less need for language-level support for XML, JSON, etc. There are some fantastic Scala JSON libraries that provide very clear and concise ways to construct and navigate JSON, including (my personal favorite) [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io/), [Play JSON](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson) (a close second), [Json4s](http://json4s.org/), and [spray-json](https://github.com/spray/spray-json) (based on [sjson](https://github.com/debasishg/sjson)).

(As a side note, the Scala XML library ecosystem is much less rich, perhaps in part precisely *because* there's XML support—however broken—in the standard library.)